# Understanding garbage collection data

Tags: garbage-collection

All,

I am using the following VM switches while running my program.  The program has a known memory leak.

Initially the heap gets full and I understand the reason of OutOfMemoryError.  But later (124.283) a Full GC reclaims some space.  So why am I still getting OutOfMemoryError?

Thanks in advance

### VM Arguments

-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xms32m -Xmx32m

### Here is the GC data

---

Heap full

---

123.540: [Full GC 123.540: [Tenured: 21888K->21887K(21888K), 0.1215501 secs] 31679K->31679K(31680K), [Perm : 2054K->2054K(12288K)], 0.1216037 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.00, real=0.13 secs] 
123.665: [Full GC 123.665: [Tenured: 21887K->21887K(21888K), 0.1504579 secs] 31679K->31575K(31680K), [Perm : 2054K->2054K(12288K)], 0.1505627 secs] [Times: user=0.16 sys=0.00, real=0.16 secs] 
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: disposed component
    at sun.java2d.windows.GDIWindowSurfaceData.initOps(Native Method)
    at sun.java2d.windows.GDIWindowSurfaceData.(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.windows.GDIWindowSurfaceData.createData(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.createSurfaceData(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.ScreenUpdateManager.createScreenSurface(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.d3d.D3DScreenUpdateManager.createScreenSurface(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.replaceSurfaceData(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.replaceSurfaceData(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
123.829: [Full GC 123.829: [Tenured: 21887K->21887K(21888K), 0.1306163 secs] 31679K->30695K(31680K), [Perm : 2056K->2056K(12288K)], 0.1306809 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.00, real=0.13 secs] 
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
124.040: [Full GC 124.040: [Tenured: 21888K->21887K(21888K), 0.1259948 secs] 31680K->27400K(31680K), [Perm : 2057K->2057K(12288K)], 0.1260596 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.00, real=0.13 secs]

---

Heap memory is reclaimed in the following Full GC

---

124.283: [Full GC 124.283: [Tenured: 21888K->15215K(21888K), 0.0945810 secs] 31680K->15215K(31680K), [Perm : 2057K->2055K(12288K)], 0.0946383 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.09 secs] 
124.829: [GC 124.829: [DefNew: 8704K->988K(9792K), 0.0079326 secs] 23919K->16203K(31680K), 0.0079854 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: I think it is because the program is allocating the same memory leak segment again and again .

Comment: @Imposter did not follow.  Could you elaborate?